# Not able to get values from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, frontend

like below i am passing the values to the function but not able to get any values from in return. i need values in vm.phoneNumberStatus
Trying to get values from *phone_status* variable

Here is the HTML where I bounded

```
<span ng-if="vm.phoneNumberStatus.VerificationStatus=='Valid'"> {{vm.phoneNumberStatus.VerificationStatus}} </span>  


vm.verifyNumber(vm.phoneNumberStatus, vm.CandidateInfo1[0].Phone_Mobile, vm.currentMPhoneStatus)

vm.verifyNumber = function (phone_status, number, currentStatus) {
    return factory.getTableObj('PhoneVerificationDetails', {
        PartitionKey: api.Emp_Id
    })
    .then(function (vfdata) {
        phone_status = vfdata.find(function (s) {
            vm.trimmedNumber = number.replace(/[- )(]/g, '')
            return s.To === vm.trimmedNumber
        });
        currentStatus = phone_status.VerificationStatus;
        if (phone_status.VerificationStatus == 'Pending') {
            vm.startVerifyNumber = $interval(function () {
                $interval.cancel(vm.startVerifyNumber)
                vm.verifyNumber(phone_status, number, currentStatus)
            }, 5000)
        }
        if (phone_status.VerificationStatus != 'Pending') {
            $interval.cancel(vm.startVerifyNumber)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: uh, instead of asking what vm is in the first place, can I know some example values? I'm a little lost

Comment: you can consider vm.phonenumberstatus is udefined but I need return phone_status object in vm.phonenumber status

Comment: If you are trying to assign a value to `vm.phoneNumberStatus` with this code, that won't work. You are passing that into the `verifyNumber` function as the `phone_status` argument, then assigning a value to the argument. That will not modify the value of `vm.phoneNumberStatus`. Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?